# Kibana match start of line/field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

How can I do a Kibana search that matches from the start of the field? I've tried the searches `message: ERROR`, `message: ^ERROR`, `message: /^ERROR/`, and `message: /ERROR/`. They will match any instance of 'error' inside `message`, including instances in the middle of `message`.

How can I match only instances at the start of `message`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `message.keyword: ERROR*`. message field is analyzed since it's a text field and your regex is matching the single token `error` that was generated by the tokenizer for your `message` field. `keyword` type fileds are not analyzed and regex search on that field is possible to return entries starting with ERROR. Please note the search regex pattern is case sensitive.

Comment: I do not get any search results for `message.keyword`, not even searching `message.keyword:*`. Should that field automatically exist, or do I need to do something special to enable it? ElasticSearch 6.2.

Comment: Can you post your index mapping ?